# Two translation suggestions: "friend of the people"? "practicioner"?

Tags: translation

I need to translate some personal info and the original text includes a phrase (literally) "friend of the people". It's a bit tongue in cheek, intended as a personal touch, since the dossier is mainly about the person's professional experience in creative areas such as advertising and promotion.

What phrase would you suggest using here? I don't want it to sound awkward, pompous or political (and the first Google hit when searching for "*friend of the people*" happens to be a Wikipedia entry on a historical revolutionary figure...).

Another word that I'm not sure how to translate is "practicioner" (?), whose meaning is supposed to be: someone valuing practical experience and accomplishments over book knowledge. Someone whose know-how comes from doing real things and who excels at getting things done.

It's not for a CV, it's a dossier for publication.

Comment: Sociopaths excepted, everyone is a "friend of the people" to some extent. But without context, let's assume this person is [public-spirited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/public-spirited), rather than a political revolutionary.

Comment: I suggest you edit off the 2nd question and ask it separately.  That is, start a new ESE question for practitioner, and remove it from this one & the title.

Comment: I don't get it. What translation are you looking and from what language to what language? If not that are you really looking for synonyms?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add more context?  Otherwise, replies are likely to be a bit scatter-shot, like the following.

'Regular guy' - A common, ordinary, man of the people.  Google shows, eg, "Mitt Romney has made a point of sharing regular-guy moments over Twitter" and "I'm just a normal guy. I'm a two-time Emmy winner, teacher of media writing, P1, Apple fanboy and loyal fan of Top Chef and The Daily Show."

Other terms that come to mind -- out-going, personable, public figure, mover and shaker.

For 2nd question:  Consider hands-on, down-to-earth, grounded, practical-minded.